# How to include a static page with custom css and js files in a Rails application

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, layout

I am working on a basic Rails application (Rails version 4.1) and I would like to include a static page in it. I have got the static page with following directory structure:

|
|- index.html
|- css folder
|-- (some css files)
|- js folder
|-- (some js files)
|- images folder
|-- (some images)

How can I include it in my application? I intend to make it my homepage btw.

I have tried using the 'layout' keyword in the controller by including the html file in the 'app/views/layout' directory. However, I have at-most been able to render the 'index.html' file but it misses any styling i.e. gets rendered as plain text.
I have been able to obtain the same result by using the HighVoltage gem.

Comment: If it's only a static page then i think you'll be better of using high_voltage gem. Can you explain what issues you had while using it?

Comment: Why can't you place all of your css, js and images in the assets pipeline as usual?

Comment: @Mandeep As I wrote, I have only been able to render the page only as a plain text i.e as a black and white sheet, with variations only in size (like a .txt file). From what it looks to me, it seems to not be including the assets that came along with it. I have tried putting them alongwith it in the 'pages' folder meant for the HighVoltage gem, and in the app/assets folder.

Comment: @AdityaBhardwaj ahh okay! I see so high_voltage doesn't allow you to use a layout file where you could load your stylesheets and js

Comment: @LcLk I tried that, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Page**

When you mention a "static" page  -- all the pages are *static* in Rails

Rails just renders HTML, using the data from your database. Much like PHP (which many developers can appreciate), Rails is a processor which allows you to populate your `view` with the data you need.

This means that if you want to make a "static" page, you just need to not pull any data from the db:

```
#config/routes.eb
root: "application#home"

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def home
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to load the following view:

```
#app/views/application/home.html.erb
Put stuff here
```

---

**Assets**

Now, the slightly trickier part is to include the right *assets* for this view.

You mention you have your own `directory` structure. Let me tell you now that you'll be MUCH better served by creating & serving *assets* from your assets pipeline.

Here's how:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<head>
  ...
  <% if controller_name == "application" && action_name == "home" %>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "welcome" %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag "welcome" %>
  <% end %>
</head>
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css
...

#app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js
...
```

Finally, if you then add the "welcome" files to your asset precompilation list, it should work for you:

```
#config/application.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['welcome.js', 'welcome.css']
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having to add each file to the precompile list?

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have custom styles and js for your home page so you'll need to do to it more any other view. **Create a controller for your home page, call it may be pages_controller. Create a custom action, lets say home, make a route for this action and then place your html inside this actions view***

Follow these steps to make it work:

- Create a controller:

> rails g controller Pages

- Create a action inside your pages_controller.rb

> def home;end

- Create a route for your action

> root :to => 'pages#home'

This will by default use application.html.erb as your layout and inside your application.html.erb you have this line

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %> #this by default load all the css from assets/stylesheets/application.css so you can require your css file inside it
```